# How to solve MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, backend

MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback
at Function.findOne (G:\Software courses\00.Coding Ninas\Course material\007. BackEnd Developer\11. Skill tests\02. Skill test2\iamroare\employeereviewsystem\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2129:11)

please helpme to solve this kind of error

i expect the above error solution

Comment: Your version of MongoDB does not support callbacks anymore you need to use a Javascript Promise. Share some example code so I can help you.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?  The course you're using is evidently out of date.

Answer (score 3):

[Mongoose v7 no longer supports callbacks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support). Promises have pretty much replaced callbacks in Javascript nowadays.

Instead of doing `Model.findOne({}, () => {})` do `const res = await Model.findOne({})`. You can only use `await` in [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Good stuff! You should also mention that the parent function needs to specify the `async` keyword. Otherwise the top-level `await` might not work